# How to change the mat type in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I used `mat1.convertTo(mat1, mat2.type())`but the type of`mat1`and `mat2` are not the same. Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide a little context? See how to do a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Not all functions are in-place. This means that if you are calling the function on `mat1`, then the destination matrix must be different. So try declaring another matrix and test the function.

```
mat1.convertTo(mat1_new, mat2.type())
```